# I am trying to work with query where I want the count of number of days between two dates to be added up to tottal

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, expression, case

RespaApp is a date & ProcessingMilestone  is a date. Now I want to know the number of days it took for a file from RespaApp date  to ProcesingMilestone date, so I am doing DateIFF sql command but it's not working. Anyone?

```
case when RespaApp is not null and ProcessingMilestone is not null  DATEDIFF(day, RespaApp, ProcessingMilestoneDate) end
```

I think it's the null cheek which is causing error, as this is being done on a software so there's a separate page to filter for nulls.

Comment: which db you are using  ..

Comment: it's not a database but a software wrapped around a large query as far as I know @scaisEdge

Comment: datediff  si for mysql ..  or not ?

Comment: i think it might be

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

In mysql [datediff()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) has only 2 parameters (2 dates), it is the [timestampdiff()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function that has 3 parameters as you described. Either take the day parameter out or change the function name.

You are also [missing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) the `then` keyword before the function call:

```
... then datediff(...) ...
```

Comment: so should i take "day" out of it ?

Comment: i took it out as you see the answer below but got an error :; Error Validating Expression :: An error occurred while processing the request. Please check the query syntax and try again.

Comment: You must provide exact details of the error, we are not mind readers! Pls note that if the error does not relate to the same part of the query, then you need to ask another question.

Comment: That error is just telling me that expression will not work

Answer (score 1):

Mysql datediff require only 2 params and return the value in days

```
select case when (RespaApp is not null and ProcessingMilestone is not null ) THEN 
        DATEDIFF(RespaApp, ProcessingMilestoneDate) else null end
from your_table
```

Comment: i put that exact word for word and got a error ::: Error Validating Expression :: An error occurred while processing the request. Please check the query syntax and try again.

Comment: Again within seconds from each other :)

Comment: @Shadow for new user  .. see  the code is really useful ..  and . link ..if useful too but need  a good review by the user  .. so i prefer first provide code and a brief discussion    but code and link togheter .. are the max .. anyway  .. thanks  ..

Comment: Okay so i know this will make you made but its saying error Please cheek the syntax and try again

Comment: the sintax is correct i have added and else conditon  .. but should be unuseful .. anyway  you show only a little part of the code  ,,  and coudl be this part is not enoigh